# Get mean of previous month in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, timestamp

I'm having a bit of trouble with my pandas data frame. I would like to compare measurements with the previous month's measurements. For this I need an extra column with the standard deviation and the average of the previous month.

I have the following table:

```
    Time    Value 1 Value 2 Value 3 Value 4
0   2020-04-01 03:42:51.531 9.189975    6.475000    3.962500    6.100006
1   2020-04-06 05:42:39.778 8.799253    7.300000    3.775000    6.119995
2   2020-04-06 06:45:55.211 8.824507    7.250000    3.600000    6.100006
3   2020-04-06 18:53:15.861 8.132523    6.312500    3.275000    6.100006
4   2020-04-07 05:39:54.373 8.772517    6.887500    3.962500    6.100006
... ... ... ... ... ...
17271   2021-03-31 22:12:32.374 9.012240    7.375000    3.750000    6.179993
17272   2021-03-31 22:43:51.906 9.038265    7.225000    3.800000    6.200012
17273   2021-03-31 23:12:27.061 9.091208    7.137500    3.887500    6.179993
17274   2021-03-31 23:44:14.439 9.109208    7.287500    3.962500    6.199997
17275   2021-04-01 00:00:00.000 9.111931    7.274812    3.973665    6.198373
```

For each of the four measurements per time step, I want an additional column (so a total of 8 extra columns) with the mean and standard deviation of the previous month. So for example, for each Value 1 measurement in January 2021, I want the Value 1 mean and standard deviation of December 2020.

I've been working on this for several days, but I can't manage to write a working python code for it. I hope someone can help me out. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use the code below to achieve your objective. It computes the mean and standard deviation for each month and then does a [lookup/merge](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp) using the `Time` column:

```py
from pandas.tseries.offsets import MonthEnd

previous_month = df["Time"].dt.normalize() - MonthEnd(1)
mu = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key="Time", freq="M")).mean()
sigma = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key="Time", freq="M")).std()

df = df.merge(
    mu,
    how="left",
    left_on=previous_month,
    right_index=True,
    suffixes=("", "_prev_mean"),
)
df = df.merge(
    sigma,
    how="left",
    left_on=previous_month,
    right_index=True,
    suffixes=("", "_prev_std"),
)
```

If your data looks like this:

```
                          Time    Value 1    Value 2    Value 3    Value 4
0   2021-01-01 01:37:49.148748   0.014568   0.041711   0.009694   0.047044
1   2021-01-01 03:29:24.939551   0.032042   0.073345   0.014901   0.051690
2   2021-01-01 06:00:53.871182   0.040758   0.105496   0.046904   0.073747
3   2021-01-01 16:59:30.672400   0.061262   0.113711   0.083658   0.073939
4   2021-01-02 01:36:59.195226   0.090762   0.115689   0.087191   0.081972
..                         ...        ...        ...        ...        ...
495 2021-04-18 05:26:41.805694  10.883107  11.917340  12.850949  13.834590
496 2021-04-18 11:52:30.124759  10.889271  11.946243  12.860569  13.870959
497 2021-04-18 13:27:59.735432  10.932131  11.977409  12.949012  13.929994
498 2021-04-18 18:58:02.280739  10.979734  11.988028  12.952918  13.991210
499 2021-04-18 19:17:01.745781  10.997603  11.995105  12.991302  13.995131

[500 rows x 5 columns]
```

It will come out looking like this:

```
                          Time    Value 1    Value 2    Value 3    Value 4  Value 1_prev_mean  Value 2_prev_mean  Value 3_prev_mean  Value 4_prev_mean  Value 1_prev_std  Value 2_prev_std  Value 3_prev_std  Value 4_prev_std
0   2021-01-01 01:37:49.148748   0.014568   0.041711   0.009694   0.047044                NaN                NaN                NaN                NaN               NaN               NaN               NaN               NaN
1   2021-01-01 03:29:24.939551   0.032042   0.073345   0.014901   0.051690                NaN                NaN                NaN                NaN               NaN               NaN               NaN               NaN
2   2021-01-01 06:00:53.871182   0.040758   0.105496   0.046904   0.073747                NaN                NaN                NaN                NaN               NaN               NaN               NaN               NaN
3   2021-01-01 16:59:30.672400   0.061262   0.113711   0.083658   0.073939                NaN                NaN                NaN                NaN               NaN               NaN               NaN               NaN
4   2021-01-02 01:36:59.195226   0.090762   0.115689   0.087191   0.081972                NaN                NaN                NaN                NaN               NaN               NaN               NaN               NaN
..                         ...        ...        ...        ...        ...                ...                ...                ...                ...               ...               ...               ...               ...
495 2021-04-18 05:26:41.805694  10.883107  11.917340  12.850949  13.834590           7.446702           8.458356           9.071314           9.948837          0.830943          0.961324          1.091647          1.102397
496 2021-04-18 11:52:30.124759  10.889271  11.946243  12.860569  13.870959           7.446702           8.458356           9.071314           9.948837          0.830943          0.961324          1.091647          1.102397
497 2021-04-18 13:27:59.735432  10.932131  11.977409  12.949012  13.929994           7.446702           8.458356           9.071314           9.948837          0.830943          0.961324          1.091647          1.102397
498 2021-04-18 18:58:02.280739  10.979734  11.988028  12.952918  13.991210           7.446702           8.458356           9.071314           9.948837          0.830943          0.961324          1.091647          1.102397
499 2021-04-18 19:17:01.745781  10.997603  11.995105  12.991302  13.995131           7.446702           8.458356           9.071314           9.948837          0.830943          0.961324          1.091647          1.102397

[500 rows x 13 columns]
```